# Как отключить приложение на устройствах скачавшего его

Tags: android, google-play

мне нужно удалить приложение с аккаунта разработчика в google play и еще необходимо чтобы у тех пользователей которые скачали мое приложение после того как я удалю его с google play приложение перестало работать есть ли способы отключения приложения у всех пользователей которые им еще пользуются заранее благодарю за ответ

Comment: Один из вариантов выпустить обновление в котором будет только один экран с текстом например: "Приложение больше не поддерживается". Именно удалить думаю нет возможности.

Comment: Это надо заранее придумывать. Например при запуске посылать get запрос, а сервер отправляет установленную переменную app_disabled=true/false и приложение ведет себя соответственно